# Authentication of my app users to Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an iOS and Android apps and want to integrate Firebase to manage chat between my app users.

I'm wondering what is the scenario to follow to implicitly authenticate my app users to Firebase when they are already authenticated to my app.

My app uses OAUTH2 to get accessToken from my backend (Authorization server).

Answer (score 0):

If you already are authenticating your user with OAuth 2.0 using Google or Facebook, you can use signInWithCredential to sign-in to Firebase with the OAuth access token. This is well documented in Firebase docs:

Here is the link for Android Facebook sign-in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Here is the link for iOS Facebook sign-in:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my case the provider of the OAuth2 tokens (the authorization server) is my own server. What should I use in this case

Comment: You can use Firebase custom auth. You just need to provide the unique user id when minting a custom token. You mint the custom token using the Admin SDKs and then sign in with the custom token using signInWithCustomToken on the client side.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, the Admin SDK. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing I'm missing in their documentation is "How can my Authorization server send the generated token to Firebase?". In the documentation, they mention the use of **admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)** which lets Firebase generate the  token. How should I do to make Firebase use **my own generated** token?

Comment: You go through your OAuth flow, in the last step where you generate your OAuth access token, you use the admin SDK to mint the custom token with your user's uid. You return your OAuth response to the client with the custom token. You then call the api signInWithCustomToken to complete sign-in. Just look up that API. It is pretty trivial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth

Comment: I got this, but what I can't find is how can I use the Admin SDK to mint my Access token to Firebase. All I can find is **admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)** which doesn't accept a token as parameter

Comment: Hmm, after you finish authentication on your end, you can just call that method. It doesn't take a token. This will generate a custom token. You would return it to the client to complete sign-in via signInWithCustomToken. Check the links I added.

Comment: It's clearer now. I thought I could use my own tokens. Thanks!